# Russian peasant exponentiation using tail-recursive OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I tried the no tail recursion version of Russian Peasant exponentiation and it returned like this:

```
let rec fast_expNTR (base, power) =
  match power with
  |0->1
  |n-> if n mod 2=0 then fast_expNTR (square base, power/2)
      else base * fast_expNTR(square base , power/2)
```

But in `else base*fast_expNTR(square base , power/2)`, it says expression is expected of type float but was given a type int. I don't understand the error.

Also, here is my attempt on tail-recursive fast exponentiation:

```
let fast_exp (base , power)=
  let rec helper (acc ,acc2,p)=
    if p=0 then acc * acc2
    else if p mod 2 =0 then helper(int_of_float (square (float_of_int acc)),acc2, p/2)
    else helper(int_of_float(square (float_of_int acc)),acc * acc2, p/2)
  in helper(base,1,power)
```

But it didn't compute the correct result. Please help

Comment: You're not putting in the time to ask good questions here. Which website gave you the wrong info about OCaml? (`%` is the mod operator in several languages, but not OCaml.) You should figure out one difficult thing you really need help with, and ask that one question here. It seems to me that many of your questions (such as what the mod operator looks like) would be answered by a fairly quick read through an OCaml tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your function `square` has type `float -> float` and `*` is the integer multiplication.

Comment: and for floats x ^ 0 isn't `1` but `1.`